# How To Enable USB Keyboard and Mouse on Boots in HP Prodesk 400 G3

Tags: windows-7, bios, formatting

I set my bios to legacy boot. I enable fast boot and virtualizations.
But during the boot setup upon choosing language the mouse and keyboard are not working.

Given the following devices:
HP Prodesk 400 G3
Fast boot and virtualization enable

Comment: UEFI mode is **always** recommended. Legacy is only for very old OSes. That's probably your problem right there.

Comment: Windows 7 was designed before UEFI was invented. All my PC's that have uefi installed and run in legacy mode with W7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About this problem. I used PS2 connectors, because all of USB ports are not working. Then when I used PS2 its works. Maybe the reason is the W& does not have drivers for the USB.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have the keyboard and mouse connected to usb 3.0 ports, and W7 does not have drivers for 3.0.

Try using the USB 2.0 ports,

4 - rear center facing usb ports are 2.0

Here are the W7 drivers after you get it installed
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-prodesk-400-g3-small-form-factor-pc/8354586